# i want value of input type <input> in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, input, html-lists

my code is

```
<ul id="start">
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="abc" >
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't id of Ii and Input Type
 I want value of input type in javascript

in css we use

```
#start li input{
//code 
}
```

how to do same thing in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
var value = document.querySelector("#start li input").value
```

Or if you can't use that:

```
var value = document.getElementById("start").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the first element with

```
document.getElementById('start').children[0].children[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 document.querySelector("#start li input").value;
```